# Running Web Component Tester Locally

Tags: unit-testing, polymer, web-component-tester

Do I have to install Web Component Tester (`wct`) globally? E.g. `npm install -g web-component-tester`. Is there any way to install it as a local module? E.g. `npm install web-component-tester`. If so, how do I execute it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can install the `web-component-tester` locally with the command you mentioned.

To execute it you can run `./node_modules/web-component-tester/bin/wct`.